# Unable to delete text from input after adding regex to it

Tags: javascript

I've this javascript code:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-field-name="CNPJ"] input').addEventListener('keydown', (inheritance) => {
        let value = inheritance.target.value;
        console.log(value.length)
        if (value.length >= 18) {
            inheritance.preventDefault()
            inheritance.stopPropagation()
            return
        }
        value = value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2")
        value = value.replace(/^(\d{2}).(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3")
        value = value.replace(/.(\d{3})(\d)/, ".$1/$2")
        value = value.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2")
        inheritance.target.value = value;
    })
```

The problem that I'm having is when the input's value reach the maximum length (I stipulated in the code), I'm unable to delete the text.

I don't know what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preventing default input behaviour in this line when you reach the max length. Remove it and add a maxlength check in the HTML code instead.

```
  if (value.length >= 18) {
      inheritance.preventDefault()
      inheritance.stopPropagation()
      return
  }
```

I am not sure why this line is required since you can do something similar in HTML:

```
<input maxlength="18"></input>
```

Can you elaborate why maxlength has to be done in JavaScript?

Alternatively you can add a Backspace or similar key checks in your logic:

```
if (
    value.length >= 18
    && inheritance.key !== "Backspace"
  ) {
    inheritance.preventDefault()
    inheritance.stopPropagation()
    return
}
```

I don't recommend detecting specific keys personally since HTML considers a lot more edge cases than a single key check will.

Check out the MDN doc on [input pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).

Comment: I added that key part in my logic and it work, thanks :D. The reason that I needed to do those things in javascript is because my code is interacting with HTML of an already existing web page, and I don't think I can edit the HTML of that page like you have showed.

Comment: It may be possible to select the element and attach the `maxlength` property to it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the previous implementation cause `inheritance.preventDefault()` makes the function not to produce an input when the length is greater than or equal to 18

The better way is to scratch that `if statement` then add `maxlength="18"` attribute to the input element.

**See the demo :**

That was because of the if statement

```js
document.querySelector('div[data-field-name="CNPJ"] input').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  value = value.replace(/\D/g, "")
  value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1.$2")
  value = value.replace(/^(\d{2}).(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2.$3")
  value = value.replace(/.(\d{3})(\d)/, ".$1/$2")
  value = value.replace(/(\d{4})(\d)/, "$1-$2")
  e.target.value = value;
})
```

```html
<div data-field-name="CNPJ">
  <input type="text" maxlength="18" />
</div>
```